# Почему не перерисовывается значение state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function App() {
  const input1 = React.createRef();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    countries: ["London", "Paris", "Berlin"],
    currentCountry: "London",
  });

  function handleChange() {
    let obj = state
    obj.currentCountry = input1.current.value
    setState(obj);
    console.log(state)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>{state.currentCountry}</p>
      <select ref={input1} onChange={handleChange}>
        {state.countries.map((item, i) => {
          return <option key={i}>{item}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}
```

Почему в state значение currentCountry меняется, а при выводе в абзац остаётся таким же.

Comment: Потому что реакт сравнивание старое и новое значение с помощью Object.is. Попробуйте сравнивать старое и новое и убедитесь что получите true. В данном случае можете использовать Object.assign или что-то по типу const newObj = { ...obj, currentCountry: input1.current.value }

Comment: Сработало с assign, спасибо